# passing partitions to another function in clojure

Tags: clojure, higher-order-functions

I am just started clojure but I can't seem to figure out using/creating higher order functions.

I have partitioned a collection and I want to pass that into another function that will do something to the window of items. I am not sure how to go about doing this.

```
(def foo [:a :b :c :d :e])

(partition 3 1 foo)
;;=> ((:a :b :c) (:b :c :d) (:c :d :e))

(defn bar [start next end])
```

I think the basic outline would be.

```
(defn faz [collect]
    (partition 3 1 collect)
    ;;maybe do here before passing
    (bar stand next end)
)
```

I might be getting ahead of myself but I also see there are other functions like reduce and apply they can do something similar right? Although, most examples I see have it so they perform operations on two items at a time which are similar to `(partition 2 1 foo)`

Comment: If you get a single partition bound to e.g. `x`, then you can call `bar` on it by using `(apply bar x)`. If you want to get N results of `bar` from N partitions, then you can use `mapv` for that (or `map` if you need laziness or a transducer, but probably not at this point).

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like

```
(defn bar [start next end])


(defn faz [collect]
  (let [partitions (partition 3 1 collect)]
    (apply bar partitions)
    ))
```

or if you want to call `bar` directly, you can use destructuring

```
(defn bar [start next end])

(defn faz [collect]
  (let [partitions (partition 3 1 collect)
        [start next end] partitions]
    (bar start next end)
    ))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is general and there is more ways to achieve this, based on expected result and used function.

If you want to return sequence of results, use [`map`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/map) and [`apply`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/apply):

```
(defn results-for-triplets [collect]
  (map #(apply + %) (partition 3 1 collect)))

(results-for-triplets [1 2 3 4 5])
=> (6 9 12)
```

For better readability, you can use [`->>`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/-%3E%3E) macro.

```
(defn results-for-triplets [collect]
  (->> collect
       (partition 3 1)
       (map #(apply + %))))

(results-for-triplets [1 2 3 4 5])
=> (6 9 12)
```

You can avoid `apply`, if your function [destructures](https://clojure.org/guides/destructuring) passed sequence:

```
(defn sum3 [[a b c]]
  (+ a b c))

(defn results-for-triplets [collect]
  (->> collect
       (partition 3 1)
       (map sum3)))

(results-for-triplets [1 2 3 4 5])
=> (6 9 12)
```

If you want to call function for side effect and then return `nil`, use [`run!`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/run!):

```
(defn print3 [[a b c]]
  (println a b c))

(defn results-for-triplets [collect]
  (->> collect
       (partition 3 1)
       (run! print3)))

(results-for-triplets [1 2 3 4 5])
1 2 3
2 3 4
3 4 5
=> nil
```